# Setting the Physics Body, of a Sprite Node, starts flickering the animation

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have set the a sprite node, which is set to move in a circular motion.

Here is the code.

```
-(void) setUpMonkey{

SKTexture * monkey1 =[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"monkey_walk_right_1_angle.png"];
SKTexture *monkey2= [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"monkey_walk_right_2_angle.png"];
monkey1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

monkey2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringLinear;

SKAction *_walking = [SKAction repeatActionForever: [SKAction animateWithTextures:@[monkey1,monkey2] timePerFrame:0.2]];

_monkey =[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:monkey1];

[_monkey runAction:_walking];
[_monkey setScale:0.5];
[self addChild:_monkey];

CGMutablePathRef circleMonkey = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(circleMonkey, NULL, CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 80 + _monkey.frame.size.height/2, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:circleMonkey asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES
                                    duration:5.0];

SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];

[_monkey runAction:forever];
}
```

This works well.
But once I set the Physics Body property of the _monkey (SKSpriteNode),

```
-(void) setUpMonkey{

SKTexture * monkey1 =[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"monkey_walk_right_1_angle.png"];
SKTexture *monkey2= [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"monkey_walk_right_2_angle.png"];
monkey1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

monkey2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringLinear;

SKAction *_walking = [SKAction repeatActionForever: [SKAction animateWithTextures:@[monkey1,monkey2] timePerFrame:0.2]];

_monkey =[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:monkey1];

[_monkey runAction:_walking];
[_monkey setScale:0.5];

_monkey.physicsBody =[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(_monkey.frame.size.width , _monkey.frame.size.height)];
[self addChild:_monkey];


CGMutablePathRef circleMonkey = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(circleMonkey, NULL, CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 80 + _monkey.frame.size.height/2, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:circleMonkey asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES
                                    duration:5.0];

SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];

[_monkey runAction:forever];
}
```

The whole animation is messed up. It starts flickering, and also the sprite starts moving in an eliptical motion.
What happens when I set the PhysicsBody?

P.S
I am a beginner at iOS Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use physics and move/follow actions together.

The physics body will move your node through forces and manual velocity changes. Using actions that change the position of the node will mess with the physics behavior, and vice versa. Stick to one or the other.

At best you can disable gravity for the physics body, preferably also disable any collision feedback. Then you can move the node with physics body through actions and still be able to rely on physics contact callbacks to report contacts (but the body should resolve the collision forces, otherwise you get the same problem again).

Comment: Aa.. I din't realise that the gravity of the world is set by default..  I just changed that to zero and it started working.. Thanks a lot :)